# Creating an Array and filling it with ADC values - STM32L476G

Tags: arrays, global-variables, adc, stm32cubeide

I was wondering how to create an array on STM32cubeIDE. I like to fill this array with values from an independent LDR.

Below is the set-up code for the ADC:

```
/*User Begin PV*/
```

```
uint16_t value_DAC = 0;uint16_t value_ADC =0;uint32_t state_DAC = 0;
```

```
/*User Begin 2*/
```

```
HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED); // Calibrate ADC
```

```
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *) &value_ADC, 1); // Start ADC with DMA
```

```
HAL_DAC_Start(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_2); // Start the DAC
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I haven't tried anything yet because I really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is a bit unclear.
if you could already read the adc value, the only thing to do on top is to make a simple c array like `int value_ADC[20];` and then read and store the adc value in it periodically with your desired interval.
to do so you can either use blocking method with a loop if the only thing you wanna do is to read adc like this:

```
    while (1)
    {
        //shifting each array element to right by one
        //so we can save the new value on index 0
        for (int i = 20 - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            value_ADC[i] = value_ADC[i - 1];
        }

        //read adc value and save it on index 0 of array
        HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
        HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1);
        value_ADC[0] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);

        //whatever you wanna do with adc values

        HAL_Delay(10);//change to desired interval
    }
```

or non-blocking if you have parallel tasks, with "timer interrupts" that you can learn more about by searching the term. if the speed of timer was too high you can use a counter to read adc value every 100th interrupt for example and also reset the counter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help this really simplifies it from what I have now

Comment: @kevin you're welcome, please consider upvoting and accepting as helpful answer(tick symbol) if it helped.